# Query regarding regex format for specific filename

Tags: regex, file-rename

I have to rename some files - thought of automating the process using regex.

The current filename format is:

```
CompanyName-Invoice-04-Date-2021-01-06-Client-Abra-Paid
CompanyName-Invoice-20-Date-2022-10-10-Client-Abra-Cadabra-Paid
CompanyName-Invoice-99-Date-2023-12-31-Client-Boombastic-Fantastic-Paid
```

I want to change the filename format to:

```
CompanyName-Invoice-04-Client-Abra-Date-2021-01-06-Paid
CompanyName-Invoice-20-Client-Abra-Cadabra-Date-2022-10-10-Paid
CompanyName-Invoice-99-Client-Boombastic-Fantastic-Date-2023-12-31-Paid
```

I have managed to group together till the date part using:

```
^([A-Za-z0-9-]{17})([-]{1})([A-Za-z0-9-]{15})([-]{1})
```

I intentionally kept the '-' separate so I could manipulate it later if I want to.

I am falling short when it comes to grouping the '**client name**' and '**Paid**' part of the format.

Would really appreciate any help grouping the last two parts.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you don't need to put the `-` inside `[]`. And `{1}` is never necessary; everything matches exactly once unless you use another quantifier.

Comment: What are you matching with `[A-Za-z0-9-]{17}`? There are 19 characters in `CompanyName-Invoice`

Comment: Split them into 4 parts, then reorder them as you see fit: [`^((?:\w+-){2}\d{2})-(Date-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})-(.+)-(\w+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/ouHFHL/1)

Comment: Hi Barmar, thank you for your comment. It was a typo - apologies. I've changed the regex code to -> ^([A-Za-z0-9-]{19})(-)([A-Za-z0-9-]{18})(-). But Stack is not letting me edit the question.

Comment: Hi InSync, that is a really nice regex code. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you InSync, Barmar, lemon for your answers. All three answers work well. Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try matching using lookarounds:

```
(?<=-\d{2}-)(Date-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})-(.*)(?=-Paid)
```

Then replace the match with the groups inverted in position `\2-\1` (Python flavor).

**Regex Explanation**:

- `(?<=-\d{2}-)`: positive lookbehind (what's before the match)

  - `-\d{2}-`: dash followed by two digits and another dash
- `(Date-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})`: **Group 1**, containing your date
- `-`: dash
- `(.*)`: **Group 2**, containing your string
- `(?=-Paid)`: positive lookahead (what's after the match)

  - `-Paid`: dash followed by "Paid"

Check the regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/nAKDPw/1).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^([a-zA-Z\d-]+)(-)(Date-\d{4}\d{2}-\d{2})(-)(Client-[a-zA-Z\d-]+)(-)([a-zA-Z\d])+$
```

This matches

- any string of letters, numbers, or hyphens
- followed by a hyphen
- followed by `Date-` and a date
- followed by a hyphen
- followed by `Client` and any string of letters, number, or hyphens
- followed by a hyphen
- followed by a single word

Answer (score 0):

Be very specific if you can:

```
/(CompanyName\-Invoice-[0-9]{2})-(Client-[-A-Za-z]{2,})-Date-([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})-Paid/

Group 1 = company_name_invoice_# e.g. "CompanyName-Invoice-99"
Group 2 = date e.g. "2023-12-31"
Group 3 = client_blah "Client-Boombastic-Fantastic"


new = (\1)-(\3)-Date-(\2)-Paid
```